# C#, visual studio code, debugger, Error processing 'configurationDone' request. Unknown Error: 0x89720010,

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

Has anyone seen this particular Visual Studio Code error, when using the debugger?  I have narrowed it down to this error code, and there does not appear to be any online resource on this issue.

I am using Visual Studio Code to do some C# debugging. And it is narrowed down to this issue. I have a simple piece of code in a XUNIT project like this:

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace xunitexample
{
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World...");
        }
    }    
}
```

The project file `xunitexample.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The `launch.json` is:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
// Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
// For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "test",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/xunitexample.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

}

and the `tasks.json` is:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "test",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/xunitexample.csproj"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems to run to completion with the output screen of:

---

```
Build started, please wait...
Build completed.

Test run for c:\Users\carlf\Documents\Solidity\geth\xunitexample\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\xunitexample.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.5726113]   Discovering: xunitexample

[xUnit.net 00:00:00.6819027]   Discovered:  xunitexample

[xUnit.net 00:00:00.7242235]   Starting:    xunitexample
```

Hello World...

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.8617720]   Finished:    xunitexample
Total tests: 1. Passed: 1. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.

Test Run Successful.

Test execution time: 1.5850 Seconds
```

--

But still it shows this configuration error message at the top of the status screen, in big glaring RED:

> Error processing 'configurationDone' request. Unknown Error: 0x89720010

What is it and why it is being displayed?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I just upgraded vs code and I'm seeing this same issue...

Answer (score 1):

This VS Code issue is fixed now. See VS Code version 1.12.1.
It has worked here!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have started to fix the issue:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1431